# Unityでゲーム画面上の点の色をリアルタイムで取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: unity2d

Unityでゲーム画面のいろを取得したいです

Answer (score 0):

こちらの[サイト](https://qiita.com/OKsaiyowa/items/3664afd9df826b979243)が参考になるかもしれません。この記事では[UniRx](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx)を使用して色の取得を行っているそうです。